# NextJS: Axios does not decode data value on the server side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

When I try to use Axios in serverSideProps I get a strange data value, at first, I thought it was a Redux issue, but no, if I replace Axios with Fetch everything works correctly. Outside of serverSideProps Axios also works well.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`
  );
  console.log(res.data);

  // const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`);
  // console.log(await res.json());

  return {
    props: {} 
  };
}
```

[value I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGwXM.png)

[codeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/festive-carlos-p2di7t)

Comment: why `await res.json()` is commented?

Comment: @itachi res.json() used for the fetch(), here I am using Axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with axios v1.2.0 itself. You need to add `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` headers as a temporary solution until the issue is solved:

```
const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
    }
})
```

[Github discussion about this problem.](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Axios - I think dealing with gzip encoding.  You can see the issue [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298).

Workaround:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchJob = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchJobs",

  async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      headers: { Accept: "application/json", "Accept-Encoding": "identity" }
    });
    const data = res.data;
    // const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
    // const data = await res.json();
    console.log(res);

    return data;
  }
);
```